# is it possible to integrate Moodle-based websites?

Tags: moodle

I would like to connect my existing website into another website that uses Moodle(VLE). Is it possible to connect two virtual learning environment(VLE) websites that both websites use Moodle?

let's say there's a 2 websites namely, w1 and w2. w1 and w2 uses Moodle. Suppose I created some activities in w1. So, what I would like to do is when i visit w2, I can see/access all the activities that I've created in w1. So the question is HOW?

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"?

Comment: Hi Jakub, the second paragraph explains the word "connect" that I would like to do. thanks in advance for your response

Answer (score 1):

You can use mnet to integrate two Moodle sites and share resources.

Refer http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/MNet for more details.

Comment: What about the Moodle API? do I need to use this?

Comment: If both sites are Moodle, then you don't need to use the API

Comment: How about the first site isn't Moodle-based? is it still possible to connect it? do I need to use Moodle API at this scenario? Pls reply. Thanks in advance for you response.

Comment: If the first site is not based on Moodle, then you should develop a plugin/module which uses Moodle Web Services API and connect to the Moodle(second site).

Comment: So in that case, do I still need to use the MNet( http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/MNet)?

Comment: if I created a plugin/module that uses Moodle Web Services API, then what? How do i CONNECT it to the moodle-site? what tools should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Is it the courses you want to share? You could use community hub.

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Community_hubs